# QML custom view for QAbstractItemModel sub-class with tree structure

Tags: qt, treeview, qml

I have a QT C++ tree Model which f.e. look like this:

```
RootIndex
 - Index1
   - ChildIndex11
     - ChildChildIndex111
   - ChildIndex12
     - ChildChildIndex121
     - ChildChildIndex122
   - ChildIndex13
 - Index2
...
```

The maximum depth of my model **== 4**. Also model is dynamic, so indexes could be added\deleted and moved within tree (but not break ***max depth == 4*** property).

I want to render this model with QQuickView using QML, but not as usual tree, 
I want it too look like nested rectangles:

[image]

Could it be reached with **TreeView** QML Type (As I understand this is the only type that supports Tree QT models) ?

Comment: Consider QML Repeater: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html and provide each repeater with the model of certain index / level.